How to use custom color palette in @angular/material-experimental - Expected $config.color.primary to be a valid M3 palette
X [ERROR] Expected $config.color.primary to be a valid M3 palette.
angular 17
I can't find the expected valid M3 palette for @angular/material-experimental anywhere.
tryied this in styles.scss:
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@use "@angular/material-experimental" as matx;

$primary-palette: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #191027,
    20: #2b1a41,
    25: #3d245c,
    30: #4f2f76,
    35: #9257c5,
    40: #654083,
    50: #79539b,
    60: #9d80b7,
    70: #c1aed3,
    80: #e5dbef,
    90: #e5ddee,
    95: #e9e3ef,
    98: #ebe7ef,
    99: #efecf1,
    100: #ffffff,
);

$m3-custom-theme: (
    color: (
        primary: $primary-palette
    ),
);

$light-theme: matx.define-theme($m3-custom);

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    @include mat.button-theme($light-theme);
}


Short answer:
Example of @angular/material@17.3.1 using a M3 custom colour theme instackblitz
Long answer:
First let's consider how the docs show how it's possible to use a prebuilt theme:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use '@angular/material-experimental' as matx;

$my-theme: matx.define-theme((
  color: (
    theme-type: dark,
    primary: matx.$m3-azure-palette,
  )
));

@include mat.core(); // core component styles (unthemed)

html {
  // Apply the base theme at the root, so it will be inherited by the whole app.
  @include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
}

Then, since there is no documentation on configuring a custom colour theme (as of version 17.3.1) I looked into the the code for the prebuilt themes in https://github.com/angular/components/blob/17.3.1/src/material-experimental/theming/_m3-palettes.scss.
Unfortunately there are a few private methods in _m3-palettes.scss e.g. _apply-patches, so as a workaround I dumped out the $m3-azure-palette variable and used that as the starting point for our own custom colour theme. This compiles for me:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use '@angular/material-experimental' as matx;

// output from @debug matx.$m3-azure-palette
$my-m3-colours: (
  0: #000000,
  10: #001b3f,
  20: #002f65,
  25: #003a7a,
  30: #00458f,
  35: #0050a5,
  40: #005cbb,
  50: #0074e9,
  60: #438fff,
  70: #7cabff,
  80: #abc7ff,
  90: #d7e3ff,
  95: #ecf0ff,
  98: #f9f9ff,
  99: #fdfbff,
  100: #ffffff,
  secondary: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #131c2b,
    20: #283041,
    25: #333c4d,
    30: #3e4759,
    35: #4a5365,
    40: #565e71,
    50: #6f778b,
    60: #8891a5,
    70: #a3abc0,
    80: #bec6dc,
    90: #dae2f9,
    95: #ecf0ff,
    98: #f9f9ff,
    99: #fdfbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  neutral: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #1a1b1f,
    20: #2f3033,
    25: #3b3b3f,
    30: #46464a,
    35: #525256,
    40: #5e5e62,
    50: #77777a,
    60: #919094,
    70: #ababaf,
    80: #c7c6ca,
    90: #e3e2e6,
    95: #f2f0f4,
    98: #faf9fd,
    99: #fdfbff,
    100: #ffffff,
    4: #0a0b0c,
    6: #101013,
    12: #1e1f23,
    17: #292a2d,
    22: #343438,
    24: #39393d,
    87: #dbdade,
    92: #e9e8ec,
    94: #efedf1,
    96: #f5f3f7,
  ),
  neutral-variant: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #181c22,
    20: #2d3038,
    25: #383b43,
    30: #44474e,
    35: #4f525a,
    40: #5b5e66,
    50: #74777f,
    60: #8e9099,
    70: #a9abb4,
    80: #c4c6d0,
    90: #e0e2ec,
    95: #eff0fa,
    98: #f9f9ff,
    99: #fdfbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
  error: (
    0: #000000,
    10: #410002,
    20: #690005,
    25: #7e0007,
    30: #93000a,
    35: #a80710,
    40: #ba1a1a,
    50: #de3730,
    60: #ff5449,
    70: #ff897d,
    80: #ffb4ab,
    90: #ffdad6,
    95: #ffedea,
    98: #fff8f7,
    99: #fffbff,
    100: #ffffff,
  ),
);

$theme: matx.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: $my-m3-colours,
      tertiary: matx.$m3-blue-palette,
    ),
  )
);

@include mat.core();
@include matx.color-variants-back-compat($theme);

:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
}




It's currently not possible according to the documentation.
https://material.angular.io/guide/material-3

I ran into this problem today as well, it seems that the pre-built themes are usable, but not custom ones;
I believe this might be resolved with Angular 18.
See - Can I use colors other than the pre-defined Material 3 palettes?

there is now a new schematics. Use this to generate your schematics. I think only available under the v19 packages
ng generate @angular/material:theme-color

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
